# how to create welcome animation screen before page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gif

i have html based website with regular "index.html" as a main page,
is it possible to load animation and then load the index.html after the animation loop ends?

i dont need a complicated solution that keep the animation run until the page finish to load..
i just need the animation loop to play ones till it ends and then load the page..
the most simple solution that u can find for me will be great.

maybe with javascript code that you put in the "index.html" that tells the "index.html" to load the ".gif" file before the rest of the page loads?

or a script that tells the "index.html" to load a ".js" file that contains the welcome screen code and animation before the rest of the "index.html" loads?

if so,
how can i do it?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a div with display:block, for the animation
2. Create a div with your final content, add a display:none to hide
3. add some js

   window.onload=()=>{document.querySelector('#animation').style.display='none';
   document.querySelector('#content').style.display='block';
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using animation only. Please check the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .animate{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: green;
    animation: animate 10s forwards; /*Control the time like 10s (10 seconds) or 2s as required*/
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        background: yellow;
    }
    50%{
        background: red;
    }
    100%{
        background: green;
    }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><h1>Body text</h1></div>
      <div class="animate">
        <button class="continue">Continue</button>
     </div>
     <script>
      let animate_div = document.querySelector(".animate");
      let continue_button = document.querySelector(".continue");

      continue_button.addEventListner('click', function(e){
        animate_div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my index.html already has divs inside, 
how can i be sure that this div will be load first and will be above all the other content until the animation will complete?
it should have "z-index" so the layer will be above all others? isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can use z-index if any other div has position:absolute

Comment: after the background animation complete, the content of <div class="animate"></div> is still visible on the page..

i the content of <div class="animate"> to disappear after the animation complete.

Comment: Ok, set the  visibility: hidden at 100%

Comment: ok now it works!  a last question:
is there an option to create a button on the page that make the 100% hidden on click? instead of the page do it automaticly?

i mean after the animation loads, instead of run "visibility: hidden;",
i want a button with text like "continue to the website"
and when the user click it, the content of the "<div><h1>Body text</h1></div>" will appear

Comment: the button still not appears on the page.. just the color animation..
i need the button to appear on the page while the animation plays
and stay on the page when the animation stops
and when i press the button (no metter if during the animation or after the animations stops) all this welcome screen will become invisible execept of what between the regular <div><h1>Body text</h1></div>

Comment: ok, then please remove the `.continue` related all css codes from css files.

Comment: the button still doing nothing when i click it..

i need this whole code to be inserted in my index.html file, so this intro will be shown before the the rest content of the index.html shows.. and when a user press the button so this intro include the button will disappear and the rest content of the index.html will be show.

Comment: I have added a `<script>` section at the bottom of the page. You need to use that.